# Why Map object showing size zero when data is populated in it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am populating a map object with response from API. Also I am trying to update the value of the map object in another function which is called from a child view. But the map object is showing size zero. My question is why the map object is empty even though it is populated in another object. I have attached two screenshots to show the non empty and empty map objects.

```js
export function Catalogue(props: CatalogueProps) {

  const [categories, setCategory] = useState([]);
  const catalogueResponse = new Map();


  function getCategoryList() {
    httpRequest({
      url: '',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then((result: AxiosResponse) => {
        const data = result.data;
        const men = {
          title: 'Men',
          id: 'men',
          value: []
        };
        const women = {
          title: 'Women',
          id: 'women',
          value: []
        };
        const misc = {
          title: 'Miscellaneous',
          id: 'misc',
          value: []
        }
        data.forEach((elem) => {
          // store data in the map
          catalogueResponse.set(elem.id, elem)
          if (elem.category === 1) {
            women.value.push(elem);
          } else if (elem.category === 2) {
            men.value.push(elem)
          } else if (elem.category === 3) {
            misc.value.push(elem);
          }
        });
        setCategory(() => {
          return [women, men, misc]
        });

      })
  }

  function updateCatalogueValue(val, category, id, type) {
    console.log(' -------- ', catalogueResponse)
    catalogueResponse.get(id);
    }


  return (
    <UiView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}} onLayout={getCategoryList}>
        {
          categories.map((elem: IAccordionList) => {
            return <View key={elem.id}>
              <List.Accordion
                title={elem.title}>
                {elem.value.map((elem: any) => {
                  return <UiAccordionListItem
                    onValueChange={(val, category, id, type) => updateCatalogueValue(val, category, id, type)}
                    elem={elem}
                    key={elem.id}/>
                })}
              </List.Accordion>
            </View>
          })
        }
      </ScrollView>
      <View>
        <UiButton onPress={() => console.log('test')}>Save</UiButton>
      </View>
    </UiView>

  );
}


export default Catalogue;
```

[image: Data is populated inside map object]

[image: Map object is empty when trying to update its value in another function]

Comment: Every time the state changes, the function component rendered again and `catalogueResponse` is reset to `new Map()`. You might have to use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to use the same `Map` object again.

Comment: @adiga hey thanks. `useRef` solved the problem